# Join two furniture panel - T joint

Tags: carpentry, joints

I have a built-in wardrobe without internal panels. I am planning to add some panels in it.

I bought 18 mm furniture panels with melamine coated.

How can I attach a horizontal panel to a vertical panel  (T-Joint) ?

Should I used some wood plugs ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The usual method is to use a jig to drill rows of holes,

[image]

then use plastic clips that press into the holes and support the shelf.

[image]

There are many variations, including metal versions, some including holes for screws.

You could use dowels but that would look slightly less neat perhaps.

Comment: Thanks very useful any idea where can I buy these ?

Comment: Shorts might do them ... but they are local to me. That's probably why shopping questions don't fare well on stackexchange websites. Try your local large national-chain DIY store.

Comment: The shelf supports are very common; the jig less so, but you can do without if you're precise in your drilling.

Comment: do a search for "shelf pins" on Amazon, tons of different types. You can also check out [shelf pilasters and clips](https://www.google.com/search?q=shelf+pilasters+and+clips) if you haven't assembled the panels yet.